# how to send string to another socket?

Tags: java, sockets

i'm trying to send string Command (Upload) from Client to Server 1 and then to Server 2 , When the Client Sends the Command , the File Already download , by it should also send offer to the second Server by command OFFER by socket , The problem that when i run the two servers , the Clientthread Doesn't send the command to the Second Server

there are Two Servers , each one of the has two Classes (Server1 : ClientThread , ServerThread) , (Server2 : ClientThread , ServerThread) .
the Server can send the command from it's ClientThread class to ServerThread class of the Second Server , i think that the problem is the Socket or the SertverThread Object or something Else ?
Why The ClientThread Doesn't send the String to the Second ServerThread Class ?
please tell me what is wrong in the lines :

this is the code part from Clientthread :

```
private void SendOffer(String filePath)
{
    try {

        for (ipPort ip : ipPorts) {
            ServerSocket sockk = new ServerSocket(ip.port,0, InetAddress.getByName(ip.ip));
            Socket sock = sockk.accept();
            ServerThread serverThread = new ServerThread(sock);
            serverThread.start();
            PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
            //BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

            for (GetList gl : getlist)
            {
                if (gl.path.equals(filePath))
                {
                    count2 = gl.count;
                    digit = gl.digit;
                    p.println("OFFER" + " " +count2 + " " + digit + " " + filePath);

                }


            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

This is the ServerThread Class :

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {
    //thread client
        PrintWriter p = null;//PrintWrite
        BufferedReader b = null;//BufferedReader

        Socket socket;
        String digit ;
        int count2;
        public static List<ServerList> serverLists=new ArrayList<>();



        public ServerThread(Socket socket)
        {
            try {
                this.socket = socket;
                this.p = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                this.b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {



                String line = b.readLine();
                line =line.replace("\\","/");
                Main_Page.Log("The Client IP is " + socket.getInetAddress() + " And the Port Is " + socket.getPort() + " The Command is " + line);
                System.out.println(line);
                String[] Split1 = line.split(" ");

                switch (Split1[0].toUpperCase())//command from client
                {
                    case ("OFFER"):
                    {

                        OFFER(Split1[1],Split1[2],Split1[3]);

                    }
                    break;


                    case ("DELETE"):
                    {
                        DELETE(Split1[2]);
                    }
                    break;

                    //MOVE digest path/filename:path/filename
                    case("MOVE"):
                    {
                        MOVE(Split1[2]);

                    }
                    break;

                    default: {
                        System.out.println("Sorry , That was Illigal Opthion");
                        break;
                    }



                }

            }


            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //exception handling

            }

            Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " +socket.getPort() + " Is DisConnected ");
            try
            {
                socket.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }

        public synchronized static void CreatePath(String value){
            try
            {

                String[] path = value.split("/");
                String str = "";
                str = str + Main_Page.file_root + "/";
                for(int i=0;i<path.length-1;i++)
                {
                    str =str  + path[i] + "/";

                    File directory = new File(str);
                    if (! directory.exists()){
                        directory.mkdir();
                    }
                }




                /*value =value.substring(0,value.lastIndexOf(0,'/'));
                File directory =new File(Main_Page.file_root+"/"+value);
            if (! directory.exists()) {
                directory.mkdirs();*/
            }


            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR");
            }

        }
        public synchronized void OFFER(String number,String digit,String filename)
        {
            int num=Integer.parseInt(number);//parse number
            String digest,Path;
            for (GetList getList:ClientThread.getlist)
            {
                if(getList.path.equals(filename))
                {
                    digest = getList.digit;
                    Path = getList.path;
                    if(getList.count<num)
                    {
                        if(!getList.digit.equals(digit))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                this.p.println("DOWNLOAD " + filename);
                                String checkifok = b.readLine();
                                System.out.println(checkifok);
                                if(checkifok.equals("OK"))
                                {
                                    //convert content file in decode base64 bytes
                                    String data = b.readLine();

                                    System.out.println(data);

                                    byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(data.getBytes());

                                    //path root file server
                                    Path path = Paths.get(Main_Page.file_root + "/" + filename);


                                    //write to fileroot/uploadfile
                                    Files.write(path, bytes);
                                    GetList ListAdd = new GetList(Path, digit);
                                    ClientThread.getlist.add(ListAdd);
                                    Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " + socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : " + "DOWNLOAD " + filename);

                                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                System.out.println("ERROR");
                                Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " + socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : " + "ERROR");

                            }
                        }
                        else if(getList.digit.equals(digit))
                        {
                            p.println("ERROR");
                            Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " + socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : " + "ERROR");

                        }


                    }
                    else if(!(getList.count<num))
                    {
                        p.println("ERROR");
                        Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " + socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : " + "ERROR");

                    }
                }

            }
        }
/*

        //require to download file for client to server
        public void DOWNLOAD(String filename)
        {
            try
            {
                //read all bytes from root server
                byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(Main_Page.file_root + "/" + filename));
                //decode bas64 in the rootfile/downloadfile
                byte[] encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(content);
                //convert byte to string
                String s = new String(encoded);
                this.p.println("OK");
                this.p.println(s);


                Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " +socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : OK" );

            }catch (Exception e){
                //exception handling
                this.p.println("ERROR");
                Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " +socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : ERROR" );
            }


        }

        */
        //require to move file for client from server
        public synchronized void MOVE(String filename)
        {
            String digest ="";
            try {
                String[] splitpoints = filename.split(":");
                Path pathfrom = Paths.get(Main_Page.file_root+"/"+splitpoints[0]);
                Path pathto = Paths.get(Main_Page.file_root+"/"+splitpoints[1]);
                CreatePath(splitpoints[1]);

                // ******************************************************************************************************************

                for (GetList gl:ClientThread.getlist)
                {
                    if(gl.path.equals(filename))
                    {
                        digest = gl.digit;
                    }
                }
                //String dig = checksum(Main_Page.file_root + "/" + splitpoints[0]);
                String path = splitpoints[1];
                GetList getList  = new GetList(path,digest);
                ClientThread.getlist.add(getList);


                // ******************************************************************************************************************
                            Path temp =Files.move(pathfrom,pathto);

                        /*
                        for(int i=0 ; i < getlist.size() ; ++i)
                        {
                            if(getlist.get(i).path.equals(splitpoints[0]))
                            {
                                getlist.remove(i);
                                break;
                            }
                        }*/

                            for (int i=0 ; i<ClientThread.getlist.size();i++)
                            {
                                if(ClientThread.getlist.get(i).path.equals(splitpoints[0]))
                                {

                                    ClientThread.getlist.remove(i);
                                    break;

                                }
                            }
                if(temp != null)
                {
                    this.p.println("OK");
                    Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " +socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : OK" );

                }
                else
                {
                    this.p.println("ERROR");

                    Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " +socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : Error" );
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //exception handling
                this.p.println("ERROR");
                Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " +socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : ERROR" );
            }
        }
        //require to delete file for client from server
        public synchronized void DELETE(String filename)
        {
            try {
                Path delete = Paths.get(Main_Page.file_root + "/" + filename);
                boolean  isdeleted=false;
                for(int i=0 ; i<ClientThread.getlist.size();i++)
                {
                    if (ClientThread.getlist.get(i).path.equals(filename)) {
                        if (ClientThread.getlist.get(i).digit.equals(digit)) {
                              isdeleted = Files.deleteIfExists(delete);
                               ClientThread.getlist.remove(i);
                               break;
                            }

                        }

                }



                if (isdeleted)
                {
                    this.p.println("OK");
                    Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : " + socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " + socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : OK");
                }


                else
                    {
                    this.p.println("ERROR");
                    Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " +socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : ERROR" );
                    }






            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //exception handling
                this.p.println("ERROR");
                Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " +socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : ERROR" );
            }
        }

        /*
        //check update file
        public static String checksum(String filepath) throws IOException {
            MessageDigest md = null;
            try {
                md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            }
            catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
            {

            }
            // file hashing with DigestInputStream
            try (DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(new FileInputStream(filepath), md))
            {
                while (dis.read() != -1) ; //empty loop to clear the data
                md = dis.getMessageDigest();
            }
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (byte b : md.digest()) {
                result.append(String.format("%02x", b));
            }
            return result.toString();

        }



        //require to getlist file for client from server
        public void GETLIST()
        {
            try
            {

                String filelist= "FILELIST " ;
                for (GetList gl:ClientThread.getlist)
                {
                    if(gl.path != "00000")
                    {
                        filelist += gl.path + ":";
                    }
                }
                filelist = filelist.substring(0,filelist.length()-1);
                p.println(filelist);
                Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " +socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : " + filelist);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //exception handler
                p.println("ERROR");
                Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " +socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : ERROR" );
            }
        }


        //require to get version file for client from server
        public void GETVERSION(String path)
        {
            try
            {

                boolean checkif = false;
                for (GetList gl:ClientThread.getlist
                ) {
                    if (gl.path.equals(path))
                    {
                        String send = "VERSION "+gl.count+" "+gl.digit;
                        this.p.println(send);
                        checkif = true;
                        Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " +socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : " + send);

                        break;
                    }

                }
                if(!checkif)
                {
                    p.println("ERROR");
                    Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " +socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : ERROR" );

                }



            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //exception handling
                p.println("ERROR");
                Main_Page.Log("Client with Ip : "+socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " And Port : " +socket.getPort() + " The Reply is : ERROR" );
            }
        }
        */



    }
```

Comment: A client should never use ServerSocket. Have your program work with the traditional client-server architecture before trying to get fancy.

Comment: the ClientThread is in the server project , i gived this name to this class , maybe i was should to choose another name

Comment: Yes, please. Do not try to confuse people who only want to help you.

Comment: you Alright , im sorry about that

Comment: so , what do you think the problem is ?